# Atmega8 UART not working with F_CPU 8MHz and baud rate 300

Tags: avr, uart, baud-rate

i'm using atmega 8 with F_CPU set to 8MHz
i made my code for using the UART, it's working fine so far, but i have a problem when i'm using 8MHz of F_CPU with a baud rate. it's working fine for baud rate 9600,and some other values down till about 600. i want to use a lower baud rate. but it doesn't seem to work, at least not on ISIS PROTEUS. i don't know what i'm doing wrong.
the code works exactly the same with the other baud rate values just by changing that single #define and the baud rate in the virtual terminal in proteus.

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#define BAUD 600
#define BAUDRATE (((F_CPU)/(BAUD*16UL))-1)
```

Am i the only one facing this problem? the baud rate 300 work with lower F_CPU like 2MHZ or 4MHZ. i want to use F_CPU 8 with baud rate 300, or even lower or possible.
so, any suggestions?

Comment: you use the internal crystal of the controller? Especially for UART application you should use a external one. In most cases this solves the problems.

Comment: Your problem is probably due to the UBRR value only having 12 bits: UBRR[11:0] between the UBRRH and UBRRL 8 bit registers.  The lowest bit rate having a 12 bit divisor at 8 Mhz FOSC is 1953 bps.

Comment: mmm, so you are saying the minimum baud rate i can use it 1953?
so, how come it worked fine with baudrate 600 bps?

Comment: Assuming your UART baud rate generator is running off sysclk / 16, and per Mike the baud rate registers have only 12 bits, then each bit of the register is worth 122.  (8000000 / 16 / 2^12).  So you can have baud rate settings of 122, 244, 366, 488, 610...

Comment: mmmmmmmm, well, i currently gave it a try. it works fine for as low as 488. nothing lower works fine or correct.
well, at 488, the baud rate is 1022.5 ~1023
i tried to change it a little bit, but it seems like nothing above that value works. so it seems as if the UBRR register is only 10 bit not 12 bit... any thoughts?

Comment: Going through the calculation, UBBR is 1665 (rounded down from 1665.67), which easily fits in 12 bits. This corresponds to a baud rate of 300.12, which is perfectly fine. The problem is more likely to lie with Proteus. It doesn't always act as a real processor would. (It might be using fewer bits for UBBR, for example.)